# Interchange of limit and integral in Riemann-Stieltjes improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Q. Let $\alpha:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be the function given by

[image]

and $\alpha_{n}(t)=\frac{1}{n} \alpha(n t)$. Prove for any continuous function $f:[0, \infty] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with compact support, it holds $$ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) d \alpha_{n}(t)=C \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) d t $$

I feel that the question can be deal with dominated convergence theorem, But I am not able to take the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}\alpha'(nt)$. How to proceed by utilizing the continuity of $f$ with compact support?

Comment: I don't have a proof, but since $ \alpha ' ( n t ) $ is $ 0 $ half the time and $ 1 $ half the time, the only value that $ C $ could be is $ 1 / 2 $.  You're certainly not going to get $ \lim _ { n \to \infty } \alpha ' ( n t ) = 1 / 2 $, of course.  So whatever approach works, I don't think that it's going to come from thinking of this as interchanging the integral and the limit.

Comment: Also, we don't really have improper integrals here.  Since $ f $ has compact support, there is some compact interval $ [ 0 , M ] $ containing the support of $ f $, and so all of the integrals can be thought of as $ \int _ 0 ^ M $ instead of as $ \int _ 0 ^ \infty $.

Comment: Since $ C = 1 / 2 $ and $ \alpha ' ( n t ) $ alternates between $ 0 $ and $ 1 $, it might be profitable to view this equation as $ \int _ 0 ^ M f ( t ) \, d t = \lim _ { n \to \infty } \int _ 0 ^ M 2 f ( t ) \alpha ' ( n t ) \, d t $, and then even reinterpret $ \int _ 0 ^ M 2 f ( t ) \alpha ' ( n t ) \, d t $ as $ \int _ 0 ^ M f _ n ( t ) \, d t $, where $ f _ n ( t ) = f ( t ) $ if $ \alpha ' ( n t ) $ is $ 1 $ (in other words, if $ \lfloor n t \rfloor $ is odd) while $ f _ n ( t ) = f ( t - 1 / n ) $ if $ \lfloor n t \rfloor $ is even.

Comment: Yes, this will work!  Subtract the two integrals, $ \int _ 0 ^ M f _ n ( t ) \, d t $ and $ \int _ 0 ^ M f ( t ) \, d t $.  The difference is the integral of $ f - f _ n $, and since $ f _ n ( t ) $ is always either $ f ( t ) $ or $ f ( t - 1 / n ) $, and this has an upper bound that can be made as small as you like for sufficiently large $ n $, because $ f $ is uniformly continuous on $ [ 0 , M ] $.  So the limit of the difference is $ 0 $.  (I can write this all up as an answer if you want, or you can piece it together yourself if it's a homework question.)